# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\MyControllers\GameController::update(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error when I try to update my posts

In form everything is correct I guess, because I haven't changed anything there.

Thats my form method:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('games.update', $game->id) }}">
@method('PATCH')
@csrf
</form>
```

This is my update method:

everything was working but suddenly it started giving this error

```
public function update(Request $request, $id, Game $game)
{
    if ($game->author !== auth()->user()->id || auth()->user()->cannot('edit games'))
        abort(404);

    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'district' => 'required',
        'comment' => 'required',
        'full_comment' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'sometimes|mimes:jpeg,jpg,gif,bmp,png',
    ]);

    $game = Game::find($id);
    $game->title = $request->get('title');
    $game->type = $request->get('type');
    $game->city = $request->get('city');
    $game->district = $request->get('district');
    $game->comment = $request->get('comment');
    $game->full_comment = $request->get('full_comment');

    if ($request->has('photo')) {

        $photoName = $game->id . '_photo' . time() . '.' . request()->photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $game->photo = $request->get('photo');
        $game->photo = $photoName;
        $request->photo->storeAs('game-photos', $photoName);
    }


    $game->save();

    return redirect('/games')->with('success', 'Game has been  updated');
}
```

Comment: You are mixing methodologies.  In the method signature, either use Route Model Binding by having Laravel resolve the given ID into a Game, or use an $id and resolve the game yourself, but don't do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'district' => 'required',
        'comment' => 'required',
        'full_comment' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'sometimes|mimes:jpeg,jpg,gif,bmp,png',
    ]);

    $game = Game::find($id);
    $game->title = $request->get('title');
    $game->type = $request->get('type');
    $game->city = $request->get('city');
    $game->district = $request->get('district');
    $game->comment = $request->get('comment');
    $game->full_comment = $request->get('full_comment');

    if ($game->author !== auth()->user()->id || auth()->user()->cannot('edit games')) {
        abort(404);
    }

    if ($request->has('photo')) {
        $photoName = $game->id . '_photo' . time() . '.' . request()->photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $game->photo = $request->get('photo');
        $game->photo = $photoName;
        $request->photo->storeAs('game-photos', $photoName);
    }

    $game->save();

    return redirect('/games')->with('success', 'Game has been  updated');
}
```

Comment: @NickJaiani you're welcome, don't forget to set this answer as accepted if you are satisfied with it :)

Comment: There is only one problem, I have to remove if statement to make it work, if I just copy your code I get 404 error, I think it can't read if statement

Comment: That is weird, is the `$game->author` an ID or an object ? If it is an object then you need to fetch the ID from that object. I'm not really familiar with laravel but maybe something like `$game->author->id` would make it work ? Otherwise you'd allow any user to update the `$game`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 3rd formal parameter called

```
Game $game
```

If you don’t have route model binding implementation on the Game model

Comment: if I remove Game $game it gives me this error: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined variable: game

Comment: Take the $game instantiation which is $game = Game::find($id); to the top right before your if statement